# Update changes to a tar file. (like a incremental backup)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, tar

i have a lot of data which I pack every day into a tar. As only small parts of it change, I´m wondering if it possible to keep the old jar and only update the changes ?

Comment: Search StackExchange sites for "update files in tar". This has been discussed over again and again.

Comment: mhh I did, its all about updating single files or directories but not like with rsync where it updates everythign which is different and even deletes things which have been removed.